# How do i conditionally add a list to a ViewData.Model if 2 data values from two different DB tables are equal in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, viewdata

I am attempting to create a conditional statment in ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework.  I need to create a list of models where the ID from one table is equal to data in another model's table.  How do I right this conditional statement using Linq?
Below is the code that I have so far:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      _db = new IntegrationWebDBEntities();
      //This is the statement i am having trouble with.  
      ViewData.Model = _db.Requests.Where(r => r.id == _db.Jobs.Where(j => j.RequestID)).ToList();
      return View();
 }
```

I need to only add the "Request model to the ViewData if the id of the Request table is equal to the value of RequestID in the Job table.  Note:  The two columns are linked in the SQL DB.

Comment: What kind of a relationship do you have between the two Models Request and Jobs. Is it a one-to-one or one-to-many?

Comment: Yeah, Praveen has a good point.  It would help to understand the schema and relationship here a bit better.  Also, can this value be null in the other table?

Comment: The value can be null if not job has been started for the request.  Request and job are only linked from Job.RequestID and Request.ID.  Request is linked to other tables by Request.ID as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try like this:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  _db = new IntegrationWebDBEntities();

  ViewData.Model = (from r in _db.Requests
                    from j in _db.Jobs
                    where r.id == j.RequestID
                    select r).toList();
  return View();
}
```

Comment: LOL.  I just figured this out and got it to work minutes before you posted this!  It works!  Thank you!